# Create an object in java

Tags: java

I am trying to code a main method in CustFrame to create a CustFrame object to test it so far. I got this code so far, but I`m stocked at the last line of code in CustFrame.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Label;

public class CustFrame extends Frame {
    Label custNameLbl = new Label();
    Label shipToLbl1 = new Label();
    Label shipToLbl2 = new Label();
    Label contactInfo = new Label();

    public CustFrame(Customer cust) {
        custNameLbl.setBounds(62, 65, 176, 23);
        shipToLbl1.setBounds(62, 170, 176, 23);
        shipToLbl2.setBounds(62, 175, 176, 23);
        contactInfo.setBounds(62, 230, 176, 23);
        custNameLbl.setText("Test Text");
        shipToLbl1.setText("Test Text");
        shipToLbl2.setText("Test Text");
        contactInfo.setText("Test Text");
        this.add(custNameLbl);
        this.add(shipToLbl1);
        this.add(shipToLbl2);
        this.add(contactInfo);

        this.setSize(300, 282);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        CustFrame
    }
```

}

Comment: What did you do for `Customer`?

Comment: This is silly.  You create an object in one line, then you post to stackoverflow saying the next line has you stumped because you don't know how to create an object?  Create a `CustFrame` in exactly the same way you created a `Customer`.

Comment: @nhgrif Maybe he just got the code as is..

Comment: @Dgrin91 Hmm...good point, I guess that's not impossible.

Comment: You can create an object in Java with `new Object()`.

Comment: @nhgrif Also the first creation uses a default constructor, where as the second requires a parameter, thus a *tiny* bit of extra logic. Never the less, dont assume much from new programming students.

Comment: if your constructor takes a Customer object as an argument then pass that Customer object you just created to CustFrame.`Customer cust = new Customer();` `CustFrame cFrame = new CustFrame(cust);` Have you tried anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Customer cust = new Customer();` creates a new `Customer` object. You will then use this to construct your `CustFrame` object. Notice how `CustFrame` has a constructor that takes a `Customer` object. Thus you can create a custFrame object by just doing this: `CsutFrame custframe = new CustFrame(cust);`

Comment: I`m glad that there are still people willing to help no to critize

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `cust` object to `CustFrame` contractor

```
CustFrame custFrame = new CustFrame(cust);
```